# Баг в графике android эмулятора

Tags: android, android-studio, эмулятор, avd

Приветсвтую всех.

Проблемма появилась после обновления до Android Studio 2.0.

Эмулятор теперь выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настройки эмулятора такие:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полная переустановка Android Studio, SDK, AVD ничего не дает.

Проблемма дублируется дома и на работе(Windows 7, Windows 8.1)

Как лечить?

Comment: установкой Genymotion лечится)

Comment: Благодарю, сейчас буду пробовать.

Comment: Genymotion наше всё

Comment: Всем спасибо, перешел на Genymotion

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Comment: Решение еще не найдено.

Comment: Возможно проблемма кроется в том, что апи-10 не хочет работать под виндовс. Подробнее [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36594392/android-studio-emulator-display-bug)

Comment: у меня также показывает со всеми API, не только 10-й

Answer (score 1):

После обновления до Android Studio 2.1 баг пропал.