# Android Studio 2.0 AVD manager 4 экрана

Tags: android, android-studio, avd

Привет! При обновлении до Android Studio 2.0 обновился и AVD Manager. Я создал новое виртуальное устройство и при запуске оно показывает 4 экрана устройства в одном окне с искажением цветов. Что я испортил? [image: Вот такое окно получается]

Comment: Такой вопрос уже задан. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512192/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B3-%D0%B2-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5-android-%D1%8D%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда обновился до Android Studio 2.1 все исправилось.